react-hook-form multiple form instances with validations

My UI page use case includes interchangeable form instances.
I need to render a form component, alongside a selector component which controls what form state is rendering on the form.
Meaning I need to manage multiple form states. The number is dynamic/unknown.
Moreover, each form can optionally have initial data, to render based on the form "id".
In addition, we have one submit button that needs to validate all forms instances schemas and check if they are valid.
This means a validation should be possible even if the user didn't render (choose/fill) one of the forms in its pipeline.
I use React with react-hook-form, and yup for the schemas.
I have working code but it breaks the "rules of hooks" of React.
Please see the following, especially the part with useForm calls and eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hook:
Do you have other ideas or ways to achieve those goals?
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy';
import mapValues from 'lodash/mapValues';

// Define your form schema
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required('Name is required'),
  age: yup.number().required('Age is required').positive().integer().max(25)
});

// Form Component
const FormComponent = () => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    getValues,
    setValue
  } = useFormContext<MyFormValues>();

  const values = getValues();
  console.log('getValues', getValues());

  useEffect(() => {
    // set initial values
    Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      setValue(key as keyof MyFormValues, val);
    });
  }, [values, setValue]);

  return (
    <form>
      <input {...(register('name') as any)} placeholder="Name" />
      {errors.name && <span> {errors.name.message}</span>}
      <br />
      <input {...(register('age') as any)} placeholder="Age" type="number" />
      {errors.age && <span> {errors.age.message}</span>}
      <br />
    </form>
  );
};

// Parent Component
const MultipleForms = ({ formConfigs }: { formConfigs: FormConfig[] }) => {
  const [selectedForm, setSelectedForm] = useState(() => formConfigs?.[0]?.id); // Form selector

  // Create form instances dynamically and store them in refs to persist across renders
  const formInstances = useRef(
    mapValues(keyBy(formConfigs, 'id'), config =>
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(formSchema) as any,
        defaultValues: { name: config.name, age: config.age } // Dynamic initial values from config
      })
    )
  ).current;

  // Validate all forms programmatically on submit
  const onSubmitAllForms = async () => {
    const forms = Object.entries(formInstances);
    const results = await Promise.all(
      forms.map(async ([id, formInstance]) => ({
        formId: id,
        isValid: await formInstance.trigger() // Trigger validation for each form
      }))
    );

    const allFormsValid = results.every(({ isValid }) => isValid);
    if (allFormsValid) {
      const allData = forms.map(([, formInstance]) => formInstance.getValues());
      console.log('All Forms Valid', allData);
    } else {
      console.log(
        'Some forms are invalid',
        results.filter(({ isValid }) => !isValid).map(({ formId }) => formId)
      );
    }
  };

  const selectedFormInstance = formInstances[selectedForm];
  console.log('selected form instance:', selectedForm);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Selector to choose which form to display */}
      {formConfigs.map((config, index) => (
        <button key={config.id} onClick={() => setSelectedForm(config.id)}>
          Show Form {index + 1}
        </button>
      ))}

      {/* Only render the selected form */}
      {selectedFormInstance && (
        <FormProvider {...selectedFormInstance}>
          <FormComponent />
        </FormProvider>
      )}

      {/* Button to submit all forms */}
      <button onClick={onSubmitAllForms}>Submit All Forms</button>
    </div>
  );
};

type FormConfig = {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
};

type MyFormValues = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
};

const formConfigs: FormConfig[] = [
  { id: '1', name: 'John Doe', age: 20 },
  { id: '2', name: 'Jane Smith', age: 26 }, // not valid
  { id: '3', name: undefined, age: 22 } // not valid
];

export default function App() {
  // Example form configuration array, can be dynamic

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dynamic Multiple Forms Example</h1>
      <MultipleForms formConfigs={formConfigs} />
    </div>
  );
}



Dear anonymous downvoters: Please post a comment that critiques the OP. It looks to me like good code with sensible questions and nothing that would trigger a close vote. But maybe I'm missing something? It seems like we should be able to have constructive dialog around possible improvements to the posted code.

Why it breaks the "rules"
The React Docs state that using hooks inside of loops breaks the rules of hooks as you have realised. This also jumps out of the code as it is unusual.
It's worth taking a step back and thinking about the reasons for this, as yours is a slightly greyer case if you were only considering the snippets provided, which may mislead you. It does indeed break the "rules" as defined in the React docs. And the lining rule fatefully enforces this definition of the "rules". But at the same time, the code exactly as it is now wouldn't actually cause any problems for React at all...
The reason for the rule is that it implies that the exact execution order of hooks could be non-declarative and unstable across renders since it is dependent on the behaviour of the loop the hooks in question are contained within. And if it is unstable, that does indeed break at runtime since it is a real-terms constraint that the execution order is stable.
However, in your exact case in the snippets, useForm is called inside of a loop driven by formConfigs, which appears to be constant and defined once. That means the loop will always run with the same number of iterations in the same order meaning it currently looks like it "works" despite the lint rule.
But, you have stated this will actually be dynamic in practice. It is not clear in your post, but it suggests it possibly comes over the network. Regardless, it sounds like the loop actually has no guarantee of stability at all. That means that this will likely blow up in the runtime when the dynamic aspect is implemented or be a problem waiting to happen.
It's worth noting even if it did have such a soft "guarantee", it would still be bad practice, if not actually broken, but the full explanation of that feels off-topic.
Fixing the conceptual model
Reaching for patterns like "hooks in loops" and the resulting experience of friction between those patterns and React is usually an indicator that you have a problem with your current mental model of the required solution.
It appears to me, taking into account the semantics of react-hook-form, that what you actually have here is one form, not many. Indeed, it has one submit button, which is an indicator that the "form" talking in a react-hook-form sense is really all of them. The different inner sections are just that -- subsections.
Your use case also seems to have the behavioural property that these subsections share the same fields (name, age), which is an important thing to note, as it unambiguously means the solution does not need to reach into the bigger problem of full metadata-driven form generation where the literal form fields themselves are dynamically driven. Here, it's just the default values of each subsection and the number of subsections.

I need to render a form component, alongside a selector component which controls what form state is rendering on the form. Meaning I need to manage multiple form states. The number is dynamic/unknown.

This isn't actually true. You can & should have all the state for all the "subsections" composed into one useForm instance.
If we implement this in a certain way, it also does not hinder the ability to select which subsections are visible, including switching to and from sections or validating sections they never visited.
It will also completely avoid things like the part where you reach into each form instance and call .trigger(), which is not an idiomatic thing to do in React. And also the effect that is setting the initial values when a subsection component mounts, which is, in part, a symptom of the subsections not being modelled as part of a single form.
Proposal: Use a single useForm()
First we can set the defaultValues of the single form as an object mapping ID to the values for the relevant form config, for all the current formConfigs.
We change the schema to validate against all of those sets of values.
// Schema validates object keyed by formConfig IDs (any amount), where value is values for each of those formConfigs.
// See https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/130#issuecomment-578392176

const mapRules = (map, rule) =>
  Object.keys(map).reduce((newMap, key) => ({ ...newMap, [key]: rule }), {});

const formSchema = yup.lazy((map) =>
  yup.object(
    mapRules(
      map,
      yup.object({
        name: yup.string().required("Name is required"),
        age: yup
          .number()
          .required("Age is required")
          .positive()
          .integer()
          .max(25),
      }),
    ),
  ),
);



// ...
const { control, getValues } = useForm({
  // Get formConfigs keyed by ID, which I assume is unique. An object is a better structure for this.
  resolver: yupResolver(formSchema) as any,
  defaultValues: mapValues(keyBy(formConfigs, "id"), (value) => {
    const { id, ...rest } = value;
    return rest;
  }),
});

You then just have a typical react-hook-form with a top-level single <form> element that wraps all sections and has a handleSubmit(handler) as its onSubmit. This will get all of the values.
FormComponent would no longer need to have the effect or its own <form>.
Inside the <form> in MultipleForms, it would pass the active form config ID to the FormComponent, that would interpolate this into its register() calls like register(`${props.id}.name`). And errors would be accessed like errors[props.id].name.
Since we are using schema validation, and the values are kept around even when fields are unregistered, you can still validate them if they are not visible. And also if they never even went there, because they exist in defaultValues.

First of all thanks for the detailed answer and explanation!
The working example with your suggestion can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-e2icsg?file=src%2FApp-2.tsx

Wanted to mention I had to use reset as you can see, in order to correctly refresh the right data when changing a form.

In addition, I have wanted to ask you about useFieldArray. Isn't it suitable for my use case too?  What do you think about it? @adsy

I thought about using that too. You could do -- it would work. The reason I went with this object keyed by ID's instead was mostly because an array can represent impossible states (multiple entries with same ID) whereas an object can not. Its also slightly easier to access an individual form by ID. But these are minor things. If you feel useFieldArray is more ergonomic, you could go down that road for sure. As long as its one form -- you  are all good.
